# Button onclick event won't fire

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Please help. The task is: "Write a JavaScript program to rotate the string 'w3resource' in right direction by periodically removing one letter from the end of the string and attaching it to the front."

---

```js
function moveIt() {
    var element = document.getElementById("target");
    var textNode = element.childNodes[0];
    var text = textNode.nodeValue;

    setInterval(function() {
        text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
        textNode.nodeValue = text;
    }, 500);
}
```

```html
<body>    
  <button type="button" onclick="animate('target')">click to animate</button>    
  <p id="target">w3resource</p>
</body>
```

The function works when I apply it to onload event in document.body but it doesn't work with button. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The name `animate` is already used by DOM. Just change the name of the function. It will work.

And There's no need to set a parameter of function since you are getting element by id.

```js
function moveIt() {
    var element = document.getElementById("target");
    var textNode = element.childNodes[0];
    var text = textNode.nodeValue;

    setInterval(function() {
        text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
        textNode.nodeValue = text;
    }, 500);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="moveIt()">click to animate</button>
  <p id="target">w3resource</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I'll be careful with variable names.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were calling a reserved method name, also you were using string values not variables. Changed to `foo` and it works fine.

```html
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="foo('target')">click to animate</button>

<p id="target">w3resource</p>
<script>
function foo(target){
            var element = document.getElementById(target);
            var textNode = element.childNodes[0];
            var text = textNode.nodeValue;

            setInterval(function() {
                text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
                textNode.nodeValue = text;
            }, 500);
        }
</script>
</body>
```